# Check if text exists in variable between tags

Tags: php

Search if text exists between  and  inside $data

All XML data is in $data

I want to search if 7431 exists

XML data looks like this:

```
<status>
<connection_status>successful</connection_status>
<operation_status>successful</operation_status>
<Options>
<data_2>
<data_7422731>
<id>7431</id>
<assetId>2</assetId>
<startDate>2013-03-05 11:00:00</startDate>
<endDate>2013-03-05 12:00:00</endDate>
</data_7422731>
</data_2>
</Options>
</status>
```

...
result:

echo 'Yes it was found'; // or not

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please clarify, if you want to find only the substring, no matter if in a tag or in the content? Or if you only want to find strings between tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<status>
<connection_status>successful</connection_status>
<operation_status>successful</operation_status>
<Options>
<data_2>
<data_7422731>
<id>7431</id>
<assetId>2</assetId>
<startDate>2013-03-05 11:00:00</startDate>
<endDate>2013-03-05 12:00:00</endDate>
</data_7422731>
</data_2>
</Options>
</status>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
```

It will return an object. then you have to convert this object to array using this function

```
function object2array($object) {
    $return = NULL;
    if(is_array($object)) {
        foreach($object as $key => $value)
        $return[$key] = $this->object2array($value);
    } else {
        $var = @get_object_vars($object);
        if($var) {
            foreach($var as $key => $value)
            $return[$key] = $this->object2array($value);
        } else
        return $object;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

it will return an array then after that you can find your string in array using

in_array() function.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(strpos($data, '>7431<') === true) 
        {
        //code if 7431 is found...
        }
    else
        {
        //if not found....
        }
```

Comment: so i edited it. now it shouldnt return true when $data contains 77431 right?

Comment: If there is whitespace around `7431`, it won't be found. Better avoid regexes to scrape XML completely

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strpos($data, '<id>7431</id>')) echo 'Yes it was found';
else echo 'No it was not found';
```

This will work if you just want to know if the string $data contains the required text, however if you need to parse XML look into the simpleXML API

Edit: Changed to strpos() for performance issues, and also searching for the tags, `"<id>7431</id>"` (you can also do a `">7431</"`) to avoid matching any string containing 7431 i.e. 77431

Comment: This works, but isn't recommended. The [`strstr` manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) recommends using `strpos` instead.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add before the string the char `'>'` and after the char `'<'`  and to use `strpos ()`

```
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

> Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the
>   haystack string.

**haystack**-The string to search in.

**needle**-If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.

**offset**-If specified, search will start this number of characters counted from the beginning of the string. Unlike strrpos() and strripos(), the offset cannot be negative.

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

**try this:**

```
   <?php
    $data;//= to you xml data
    $findme   = '7431';
    $pos = strpos($data,'>'.$findme.'<');

    if ($pos === false) 
    {
        echo "NO it wasn't found'; // or not";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Yes it was found";   
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If the xml have `'> 7431 <'` it will return `false`! not good!

Comment: He dont as to find ' 7431 '! he need to find '7431'!

Comment: Yeah, but what if the XML wasn't `<id>7431</id>` but `<id> 7431 </id>`. This is also valid XML and of course he wants to find such occurrences, too. So your answer isn't correct, either.

Comment: I am very sorry @pvorb, the value of <id> 7431 </id> is ' 7431 ' and the  value of <id>7431</id> is '7431' this is the definition of XML. if you looking for the VALUE '7431' you not need to find it if the key/value is like this form <id> 7431 </id>

Comment: if the xml has <id>7431<7432</id> that will fail. It will also fail for <id> 7431 </id> (with spaces). EPIC FAIL!